# Working up some alieses for Windows cmd

Tags: command-line

*Ideas gathering here!*

What would be the easiest way to make some aliases for windows xp's cmd, so one doesn't have to enter the same parameters over and over again?

For example,

```
rmdir /s would become rd (or just rmdir)
```

Comment: Too late; they already thought of that :) the builtin DOSKEY command does this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`doskey`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/doskey.mspx?mfr=true) command for this.

For your example, you would type:

```
doskey rd=rmdir /s $*
```

Comment: Should've known that ... :/ Thanks !